# How to view contents of an EBS volume attached to an EC2 instance via Terminal?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I've setup an EC2 instance and have 2 EBS volumes attached to it. I would like to view the contents of each volume. How do I view it via the terminal (cd /somePath)? I've already have a valid SSH connection to the EC2 instance.

Edit:

From the AWS console, one of the volume is `i-9167d3ff:/dev/sda1`. I tried to do `cd /dev/sda1` but I get the message `-bash: cd: /dev/sda1: Not a directory`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items in the dev directory are devices, so you can't view them directly. This in effect is the disk for the EBS volume in question. Typically this is mounted on a specific directory, such as /mnt/volumename.

If they volumes are already mounted, you can run the 'df' command to list them. This will show you the device name and the mount point. You can then view the contents of the mount point.

If they are not already mounted, then you would need to configure /etc/fstab with the correct places to mount your volumes. They will then be mounted at boot time, or by running the mount command.

Comment: Thanks for the info to get me started. I found a tutorial here http://www.randomtools.net/how-to-mount-amazon-ec2-ebs-volume-on-an-instances-file-system-76.html

Answer (score 2):

After you have attached the EBS volumes to your EC2 machine.
You will have to mount these devices.
You can see the attached devices using one of the following commands:

```
ls /dev
sudo parted -l
```

You will see many devices, including some named `sda`, `xvda`.
Now create a subdirectory in the `/media` directory.

```
mkdir /media/new
mount /dev/sda /media/new   //mounts /dev/sda at mount point /media/new
```

You can list the mounted partitions using `df -T`.
Browse your partition through the mount point; e.g., `cd /media/new`.