# How to make a directory on another hardisk on ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

I need to make a directory on my hard disk 'sdb'. How can this be achieved?

Current situation of the server:

Running the command sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL outputs this:

```
NAME FSTYPE SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda 279.4G
├─sda1 vfat 512M /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4 151G /
└─sda3 swap 127.9G [SWAP]

sdb 5.9T
```

I need to create folders on my 'sdb' drive and utilize it. How can this be achieved on ubuntu 16.04 server. Any explanation with the help of commands is highly appreciated.

Comment: See:  [How to view contents of an EBS volume attached to an EC2 instance via Terminal?](https://superuser.com/q/292134/150988)

Answer (score 0):

- You have to create a file system on `sdb` first. See `mke2fs`. Too many options to discuss here, many of them depending on your assumed usage profile. Except the type (`-t`) that should normally be `ext4`.
- Then you create a "mount point" (actually, just an empty directory) in your current hierarchy (for instance `/theshinynew6GBdisk`) and use the `mount` command to make the root of that file appear in your file hierarchy
- You can add the device (sdb) and filesystem in `/etc/fstab` to have them mounted (and checked) automatically at boot.